# Good IDE/compiler for simple C dll's

Tags: c, windows, ide, compiler-construction

I'm trying to disassemble a C/C++ DLL, and have made some progress, but I would like to create my own C DLL with the same function the original exports, and compare disassemblies.

Visual Studio adds to much crap, and when I remove the crap and build my project, the expected DLL is missing.

I need a lightweight, preferably IDE, tool to edit and build very simple C libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Answer (score 4):

[Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) is a nice and fast IDE which works well with MingW.

But it's all been asked and answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161437/best-ides-for-c-development) ...

Comment: Can't see a reason why this is downvoted - 'tis a legitimate answer.

Comment: Gave it an up for a helpful suggestion.

Comment: Dev C++ is no longer actively developed, and is not very "nice" anyway.

Comment: Didn't know it was abandoned. Still, it will get the job done with very little fuss.

Comment: Dev-C++ is a nice and fast way to add unportable hacks to your code. Need to port a few dozen console apps to Linux, all with that ever-present system("PAUSE"); garbage? You can get the job done with very little fuss. No, really, *very* little fuss! Well, okay, maybe *moderate* fuss.

Answer (score 4):

> I need a lightweight, preferably IDE, tool to edit and build very simple C libraries.

I have found that one of the best ways to do integrated C-only Win32 development is using the freely available [Lcc Win32 Compiler](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/) which comes with a built-in IDE, including resource editor.
In fact, it is really very lightweight and can be run from a USB stick with some manual tweaking.

It's indeed a [really small download](http://www.q-software-solutions.de/downloaders/downloader/show_download_locations) of just 6 mb and you can even download an optional [Win32 API help file](ftp://ftp.cs.virginia.edu/pub/lcc-win32/win32hlp.exe) which is really useful while doing development.

The compiler also comes with a [C tutorial](http://www.q-software-solutions.de/pub/tutorial.pdf), as well as good [user documentation detailing how to use the integrated Win32 resource editor "wedit"](http://www.q-software-solutions.de/pub/manual.exe), there's also an [advanced manual](http://www.q-software-solutions.de/pub/advanced.pdf) about more complex development tasks.

Comment: lcc-win32 is free for non-commercial use, if this is not a problem, then it is a very good option.

Answer (score 2):

[GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) + any text editor such as [VIM](http://www.vim.org/) is a very light alternative.

For Windows Development, all you need is inside [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

**Edit**: If you are in dire need of an IDE you can also use the MinGW tools from Eclipse with the [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) plugin. Although it *adds weight* to the solution because of the installation of Eclipse, this is what I really use to build my small DLLs (JNI wrappers in my case).

You can setup your small and direct makefiles or let Eclipse do it automatically for you and concentrate only on the source files (*.h, *.c).

The best part of using this approach instead other IDE is that you do not need Eclipse to further build the DLL, since the underlying project files generated are standard ones directly usable by integrated dev inside MinGW (or any Unix distro) such as make, configure, automake, and so on.

Comment: And MinGW can link against dlls for which no link library exists.

Answer (score 2):

MinGW adds its own crap. Install your VC express properly and save yourself a lifetime of trouble.

Btw, you don't need to use Visual Studio for its compiler or vice versa. The oddity of missing a build dll is probably because you are not looking at the right path.

If you are building C DLLs you really would benefit from its command line toolset and utilities, sdks, easy config etc. MS lock-in proprietary extensions are widely used (in context of you trying to emulate another dll), and last thing you need is chasing cross compiler issues..

Answer (score 1):

I'll second the vote for [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org), it's what I use (despite having VS 2008 installed as well). It is very simple and lightweight but has basically all the features you'd expect out of an IDE.  It comes with several predefined project templates for all kinds of C and C++ development, including templates for DLLs.

Download the version that includes MinGW and you get a complete lightweight IDE ready to start compiling.  You can also easily configure it to use the Visual Studio compiler instead of gcc if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

try [Open Watcom](http://openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page). A cross-platform product, well-supported by the community, lets you develop in DOS, Windows, OS/2 etc for a lot of platforms. Version 1.8 was released recently. Has a light-weight IDE indeed

Comment: Doesn't even remotely support the current ISO standard.

Comment: the current standard was published more than 10 years ago if we speak about C++, and most of it is supported by Open Watcom C/C++. Or are you referring to C99 standard?